# Word-wrap not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, word-wrap, xhtml-transitional

When I'm using `word-wrap:break-word` with *Browser Mode: IE9 Compatibility View and Document Mode: IE7 standards* its working perfectly fine. However when I change the *Document Mode: IE9 standards*, its not working. 
I've also tried using `-ms-word-wrap:break-word` however its giving me the same result.

Document Type Definition: DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd

Can anyone tell me why is it so and if there is any workaround to cope up with it ?

Comment: Markup? CSS? You're giving us nothing here.

Comment: Sounds familiar. Might try some of these ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394685/css-word-wrap-break-word-dont-work-on-ie9 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13903590/word-wrap-break-word-not-working-in-ie9

Comment: Put it in your question.

Comment: @showdev didn't worked !

Comment: Create a jsfiddle with an example of your code to see what you have done. Only giving us the doctype is not helping us to help you.

Comment: @seemly Checkout the jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dShringi/d6VsD/5/).

Comment: Use word-wrap: break-word; supported in IE11 and Chrome.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you need to have

```
table {
    width:100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
```

and put `word-wrap` in `table,td,th` not into `span`

http://jsfiddle.net/d6VsD/7/

Answer (score 15):

applying word-wrap property to parent of the concerned element will resolved the problem in IE9.

Answer (score 9):

**try it this way**

```
  .table tr td { 
               word-wrap: break-word;
               word-break: break-all;
               }
```

Answer (score 8):

In my case, IE did not respect the word break style until I made the span render as inline-block.

```
.selector{
    display: inline-block;
    word-break: break-all;
    overflow-wrap: break-word; /* For other browsers*/
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
-ms-word-break: break-all;
```

works in > IE9

Answer (score 1):

Adding `-ms-word-break: break-word;` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

it should work, `.your_class_name{word-break:break-word;}`, i have tested it in ie7 - ie9 and it breaks the word...